# How to preload dynamic association in ActiveRecord 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is it possible to optimize the parameterized case like this:

```
class Post
  belongs_to :author
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :post
  scope :from, -> (author) { where(author: author) }
end

class Author
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments
end

author = Author.find(42)
author.posts.each do |post|
  if post.comments.from(author).any?
    puts post.inspect
  end
end
```